# Анимация нижнего подчеркивания криво работает

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Анимация нижнего подчеркивания работает криво она на всю страницу подчеркивает

Спасибо большое кто поможет

```css
.headtext:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.headtext:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <span class="headtext">Правила РП</span>
  <a class="headtext">Discord Сервер</a>
  <a class="headtext">Вконтакте</a>
  <span class="headtext">Донат</span>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что при использование `position: absolute`, позиционирование этого элемента происходит относительно того потомка, у которого есть `position: absolute || fixed || relative`.

В вашем случае относительно `body` или даже `html`.

Укажите `.headtext` свойство `position: relative` и проблема решиться.

```css
.headtext {
  position: relative;
}

.headtext::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.headtext:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <span class="headtext">Правила РП</span>
  <a class="headtext">Discord Сервер</a>
  <a class="headtext">Вконтакте</a>
  <span class="headtext">Донат</span>
</header>
```